# WP Query Exclude and Start by Menu Order Offset

Tags: wp-query

I have a set of posts in a custom post type that I have given menu order attributes to.  I am hoping to use `wp_query` to query the first 3 by menu order, then the next 3 by menu order.

For example -

If I have a list of posts given the menu order attribute of 1,2,3 -

```
   $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'my-post-type', 
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'order_by' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

How can I perform another query like this but start on the 4th post based on its menu order so I get 4,5,6?

I figure I can use `post__not_in` and put their specific IDs, but I'd like to keep this dynamic and address the `menu_order` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use offset to number of post to displace or pass over. Like this.

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'my-post-type', 
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'order_by' => 'menu_order',
  'offset' => '3',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Comment: Perfect.  Don't know how I missed that.  Will mark accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: :) np. I am glad I could help you with this.

Comment: That's pretty smart, though i guess there's no straight way to pass in the menu_order number and directly query that.